# How to receive all data (array) from dynamic input in react.js?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am trying to receive data from a dynamic input (article), but it returns only an array with the two first element, I do not understand why, because I receive data from another dynamic input (chapitre) with no problems?

```js
{
  chapitreList.map(
    (partItem, index) => {
      return (
        <div key={index}>
          <label for="namec">  chapitre {index+1} :</label> 
          <input type="text" name='namec' id='namec' className ="form-control" value={partItem.chapitreName} />
          <input  type="number"
                  name='soldc'
                  id='soldc'
                  className ="form-control"
                  placeholder={partItem.chapitreDepense}
                  onChange={(e) =>
                    setchapitresolde((prev) => {
                        prev[index] = e.target.value;
                        return [...prev];
                      }
                    )
                  }
          />

          <br />

          {
            partItem.articleList.map(
              (artItem, inde) => {
                return (
                  <div key={inde}>
                    <label for="namec">  article {inde+1} :</label>
                    <input type="text" name='namea' id='namea' className ="form-control" value={artItem.articleName} />
                    <input  type="number"
                            name='solda'
                            id='solda'
                            class="form-control input-group-lg reg_name"
                            placeholder={artItem.articleDepense}
                            onChange={(e) =>
                              setarticlesolde((pre) => {
                                pre[inde] = e.target.value;
                                return [...pre];
                              })
                            }
                    />
                  </div>
                )
              }
            )
        }
        </div>
      )
    }
  )
}
```

Comment: This might not be your problem, but it is an anti-pattern to use the index (inde) as a "key" in React. This article explains the problems pretty well. https://medium.com/wesionary-team/using-index-as-a-key-is-an-anti-pattern-in-react-8e5db3aea3a9

Comment: Hello! I fixed a few spelling mistakes and formatted the code a bit better. It seems to me that you were missing a closing parenthesis and curly bracket, but that may be only a copy/paste issue. Your code is quite complex, I advise you to create simpler components for the chapitre and article inputs (they should also work without the bigger context). You could use twice `index` with lexical scoping, it should be ok. Labels, IDs and names should be also dynamic.